# Migrating Room Database while adding a field with @Ignore Annotation

Tags: android, database, migration, android-room

In **Room Databases**,

While adding a field to our **entity class** with **`@Ignore` annotation**,

Should we have to **migrate** our **Room databases**.

Answer (score 0):

No you do not need a migration since the field will not be saved in the database when you annotate it with @Ignore